# Pass-by-value and queue

Tags: scheme

As I understand, Scheme uses pass-by-value when calling functions. One implementation of a queue I saw is defined as following ([yet another scheme tutorial](http://www.shido.info/lisp/scheme_asg_e.html)) :

```
(define (make-queue)
  (cons '() '()))

(define (enqueue! queue obj)
  (let ((lobj (cons obj '())))
    (if (null? (car queue))
    (begin
      (set-car! queue lobj)
      (set-cdr! queue lobj))
    (begin
      (set-cdr! (cdr queue) lobj)
      (set-cdr! queue lobj)))
    (car queue)))
```

then it creates the queue as passes it to `enqueue!`:

```
(define q (make-queue))
;Value: q

(enqueue! q 'a)
;Value 12: (a)
```

How does the queue variable passed to the function can be modified if only passed by value? I read that using set-box and unbox could do the trick but it's not the case here.

From what I understand the queue variable is a pair (the car part pointing to the head of the queue and the cdr part pointing to the end of the queue). So I don't see how set-car! of a copy of that variable could change the car part of the original object itself (the queue variable).

Can someone explain to me how it really works? Is the queue variable wrapped as an address to a pair?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scheme, like most dynamic languages, *does* pass by value, but it's effectively passing *object references* (what a language like Java would call them). In a lower-level language like C, it would be like passing around a pointer to a value. The pointer itself is passed by value, but you can use it to get at the underlying (shared) value that it points to.

In Scheme, the nomenclature usually refers to this in terms of *bindings*. A binding is more or less a name that references a particular value. For example, consider the following code:

```
(let* ((a '(1 . 2))
       (b a))
  (set-car! b 3)
  (set! b 'something-else)

  (display a)
  (newline)
  (display b))
```

This will print the following:

```
(3 . 2)
something-else
```

In that example, `a` and `b` are *two different bindings* that are bound to the same value, a single cons pair. Using `set-car!` modifies the underlying value, the pair itself. In contrast, `set!` just adjusts what a given binding refers to, not the value itself, so the other binding is unaffected.

Comment: thanks for the explanation and especially why set! doesn't affect the other binding. Much clearer now

Comment: Java is also pass by value. It's very similar to scheme.

Comment: @Sylwester Yes, that's what I said in my answer. Most languages are pass by value. I don't know of a language that's pass-by-reference by default, though some languages support it (C++ and PHP come to mind).

Comment: Both C++ and PHP needs a sigil to indicate pass by reference so they are also pass by value.

Comment: @Sylwester Yes, that was my point, though it wasn't clear in that comment. They're pass by value with optional reference semantics.

Comment: so why would one need to use boxes as mentioned in this post [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304481/parameter-passing-in-scheme) to get references to variables if that's already what scheme does by default ?

Comment: @philibertin You're right—boxes aren't the *only* way to achieve reference semantics in Scheme. Cons pairs effectively function like boxes, but they store two values, not one. If you need to just store one value, you use boxes instead.

Comment: @AlexisKing: Perl is pass-by-reference by default (operations on the elements of `@_` are done to the passed variable), but it is rarely used as thus (the elements of `@_` are usually extracted out and assigned by value to local variables).